# Analytically determine that $\arctan x$ is an odd function

Tags: functions

Without producing the maclaurin series for $\arctan x$, how would determine whether it was odd or even?

Comment: It is the inverse function of $tan(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, which is odd.

Comment: Alternatively, you also know that
$$ \arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right).$$
This implies that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(-x) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I didn't realise that the inverse of an odd function is also odd but just proved it to myself haha ... @Tyler Is that an identity I should know? I have no idea how I'd derive it

Comment: If you are defining $\arctan x$ analytically by $\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$, can use the fact that an integral from $0$ to $x$ (posibly negative) of an even function is odd.

Comment: @James You can show that $\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}$ fairly quickly by using the angle sum identities. In that case, the identity above is the dual statement about the inverses.

Answer (score 2):

From a *geometrical* definition of $\tan$ and $\arctan$, their oddness follows by reflecting the right triangle $ABC$ with $AB=1$ and $BC=\tan \angle A$ along the line $AB$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some differential calculus. Applying the Chain Rule:

$$\left(\arctan(-x)\right)'=-\frac1{1+x^2}=-\left(\arctan x\right)'\implies\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x+C$$

Now just evaluate at $\;x=0\;$ the last equality and get $\;C=0\implies\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x\;$ .